# Blockchain-based services (developing & developed countries)

Tags: voting, technology, property

Are there any countries (developing or developed) that are currently under the process of implementing [blockchain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blockchain_(database)#Alternative_blockchains)-based services ([voting](https://followmyvote.com/), [property ledgers](http://www.ibtimes.co.uk/blockchain-powered-real-estate-platform-ubitquity-does-first-property-ownership-transfer-bitcoin-1569980)...)? In particular, has there been any new policies developed in this field or has there been any government investment in such technologies?

Please provide evidence to back your statements.

Related question: [Is it possible to use blockchain or public ledgers for voting?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/13519/is-it-possible-to-use-blockchain-or-public-ledgers-for-voting)